# Yii2 Advanced Template on Nginx Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, yii2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to launch my Yii2-advanced project on AWS' Elastic Beanstalk stack running an nginx server. I have been unable figure out a configuration that allows me to access the backend of the site. I have tried extending the nginx configuration via the AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Which does not work. So I modify the configuration manually via vim from the command line.

While using combinations of the following configuration settings:

https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx

To no avail. I have tried `alias` and `root` for the backend folder and each variation I get either a 404  (file not found) or 502 (bad gateway) error.

At bare minimum, this is what I've tried to add to my nginx configuration:

```
root /var/www/html/frontend/web;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

location /backend/ {
    root ../../backend/web;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check again with `/var/www/html/backend/web` full path of backend and use alias.

Comment: Tried this... getting a 502 bad gateway error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a fully working yii2 advanced app example nginx configuration. You can change it to match your needs.

App server:

- mycoolapp.com
- nginx
- php7.4-fpm

Routes:

- http://mycoolapp.com -- frontend
- http://mycoolapp.com/admin -- backend
- http://mycoolapp.com/api -- api

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    ## Listen ports config
    listen *:80 http2;
    #listen *:443 ssl http2;

    ## Site name config
    server_name mycoolapp.com;

    ## SSL config (uncomment if necessary)
    #include /etc/nginx/ssl-snippets/ssl-snippet.conf;

    ## Access and error log files path
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mycoolapp.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mycoolapp.com.error.log;

    ## Max upload size config
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    client_body_buffer_size 32m;

    charset utf-8;

    ## Gzip config
    gzip on;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        application/json
        application/x-javascript
        text/xml
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss
        text/javascript
        application/javascript;

    ## Path to app root (folder that contains frontend and backend folders)
    set $base_root /var/www/html/mycoolapp;

    root $base_root;
    index index.php index.html;

    ## Frontend app config
    ## Entry point: https://mycoolapp.com
    location / {
        # Path to frontend web folder
        root $base_root/frontend/web;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /frontend/web/index.php$is_args$args;

        ## Omit static files logging, and if they don't exist, avoid processing by Yii (uncomment if necessary)
        location ~ ^/.+\.(css|less|js|map|ico|png|jpe?g|gif|webp|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|mov|swf|txt|pdf)$ {
            expires 365d;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        ## Deny any php file in assets folder (security)
        location ~ ^/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    ## Backend app config
    ## Entry point: https://mycoolapp.com/admin
    location /admin {
        ## Path to backend web folder
        root $base_root/backend/web/;

        ## Redirect to the URL without a trailing slash (uncomment if necessary)
        #location = /admin/ {
        #    return 301 /admin;
        #}

        ## Prevent the directory redirect to the URL with a trailing slash
        location = /admin {
            try_files $uri /backend/web/index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        ## Omit static files logging, and if they don't exist, avoid processing by Yii (uncomment if necessary)
        location ~ ^/admin/.+\.(css|less|js|map|ico|png|jpe?g|gif|webp|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|mov|swf|txt|pdf)$ {
            rewrite ^/admin(/.+)$ $1 break;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        ## Deny any php file in assets folder (security)
        location ~ ^/admin/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /backend/web/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    ## API app config
    ## Entry point: https://mycoolapp.com/api
    location /api {
        root $base_root/api/web/;

        ## Redirect to the URL without a trailing slash (uncomment if necessary)
        #location = /api/ {
        #    return 301 /api;
        #}

        location = /api {
            try_files $uri /api/web/index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        ## Omit static files logging, and if they don't exist, avoid processing by Yii (uncomment if necessary)
        location ~ ^/api/.+\.(css|less|js|map|ico|png|jpe?g|gif|webp|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|mov|swf|txt|pdf)$ {
            rewrite ^/api(/.+)$ $1 break;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        ## Deny any php file in assets folder (security)
        location ~ ^/api/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/web/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    ## PHP configuration
    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        ## Rewrites
        rewrite (?!^/((frontend|api|backend)/web|api|admin))^ /frontend/web$uri break;
        rewrite (?!^/api/web)^/api(/.+)$ /api/web$1 break;
        rewrite (?!^/backend/web)^/admin(/.+)$ /backend/web$1 break;

        ## FPM config
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    }

    ## Logging and access of restricted folders
    location =  /robots.txt     { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location =  /favicon.ico    { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~* /CHANGELOG      { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
    location ~* /LICENSE        { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
    location ~* /README         { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
    location ~* /\.             { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

}
```

Comment: I literally copied and pasted this configuration and still no luck. Right now, it doesn't even serve pages, just downloads them. It's strange. Here's a pastebin of the complete I'm really at a loss here :-(   https://pastebin.com/N9rFASbP

Comment: Tried a few other things... every URL simply redirects to the homepage. Not sure what to look at...

Comment: Hi, try to change this line `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;` to `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;`

Comment: Same issue. All URLs take me to the homepage. Not sure if this matters, but I'm running php 8. Originally, I had `fastcgi_pass php-fpm;`. Any other suggestions to look at?